# Using static method in asp mvc to use it in different cases

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, static-methods

I want to khnow if this structure is good if i use it, for example i want to call a method in different controllers (not all) and i don't want to use basecontroller

#### Case 1

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
public static image GetImage(string url){
// Get image (not from database)
}
}
```

and in userCotroller

```
public ActionResult index(){
image img = HomeController.GetImage(//url of image);
}
```

#### Case 2

Create a class with the static method

```
public class ForImages
{
public static image GetImage(string url){
// Get image
}
```

and in userCotroller

```
public ActionResult index(){
image img = ForImages.GetImage(//url of image);
}
```

#### Edit

I want to know if the static method will be executes in every request or will be shared for all requests

#### Case 3

Use the static method from a view

```
@HomeController.GetImage(//url of image)
```

or

```
@ForImages.GetImage(//url of image)
```

Comment: You are asking for our opinion. So your question is primarily opinion-based. However, such questions are off-topic for Stack Overflow: Many good questions generate some degree of opinion based on expert experience, but answers to this question will tend to be almost entirely based on opinions, rather than facts, references, or specific expertise.

Comment: i want to khnow if witch my cases if true because i'm not sur if some cases are true or false

Comment: @user3457178 So you don't want to use a base controller, but you want this functionality in different controllers? In that case you'll have to copy-paste the method. Besides, it seems that the method does not use any member of the controller (such as HttpContext), thus I'd go with Case 2, IMHO.

Comment: @FeritBuyukkececi so you mean that the case 2 is also correct? the static method will be executes in every request or will be shared for all request

Comment: Regarding your __Edit__, a static method will be executed every time it is called. If your `Index` action looks like that, then the static method will be called every time `Index` is accessed. If you are worried about performance or excessive load, you should look into caching techniques. There are various approaches and surely lots of information about it if you look for it.

Comment: edit your question to only one case and say what goal you want: performance, optimization, etc so your question return unhold

Comment: don't worry, answers will come and people will tell you the other cases and their benefits

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just want to create a utility method and it is not dependent on your controller, then you can just put it in a utility class:

```
public static class Utilities
{
    public static image GetImage(string url)
    {
        // return image
    }
}
```

Then you can call it from any of your controllers, no matter what their base class is:

```
public ActionResult index()
{
    image img = Utilities.GetImage(//url of image);
}
```

Note that you should not generally be accessing your controllers from your view template. The controllers should pass data to the views and it should be a one-way flow of information from controllers to views.

Comment: just one question : Utilities class should be mandatory static too ? or i can just set the method static only ? what is the difference

Comment: @user3457178 The `Utilities` class doesn't have to be static.